# How to use RewindCond to redirect old url on example.com to the new example.fr

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

After several searches and the help of CBroe, I reformulate my request.
Here's my problem:
I took over an old site: example.com which I recreated on example.fr
I have a qr code (impossible to modify ...) which points to

[image: qrcode]

I need to redirect this qr code to [image: redirect]

On my server, I was told to delete my redirect from example.com to example.fr: it's done
Now if I type: example.com/page.html, I have a redirect to example.fr: OK

**But** if I flash the qr code, I have the message 'unsecured connection' (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
How to write RewriteCond so that the redirection is done correctly?

Thanks for your help.
Danielle

My previous question has become obsolete. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mywebsite.fr/$1 [R=301,L] 

RedirectPermanent /page1.html / 
RedirectPermanent /PAGE.html /
RedirectPermanent /page3.html / 
RedirectPermanent /document/page/7/certificat-de-purete-20180111-110132.pdf /
```

Comment: Of course it is possible. What is your actual problem with getting it done?

Comment: Thank you very much for accept to help me.
I am not an expert ....how to write what i want to do bellow?
the url www.website.COM/PAGE2.html
must be redirected to www.mywebsite.FR

My .htaccess file from www.mywebsite.FR is
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.fr/$1 [R=301,L]

RedirectPermanent /page1.html /
RedirectPermanent /PAGE2.html /
RedirectPermanent /page3.html /
RedirectPermanent /document/page/7/certificat-de-purete-20180111-110132.pdf /

Thank you
Danielle

Comment: URL rewriting is a topic that has been broadly discussed already, and is well documented. You need to make an attempt here, and show us what you tried.

Comment: @ CBroe
Sorry. I completed my answer. Did you see it?

Comment: That is hardly readable in comments. Please edit your question to include the code there instead, properly formatted.

Comment: @CBroe
It's done (sorry..)

Comment: Try and change the order, put the RedirectPermanent directives before the RewriteEngine block.

Comment: @CBroe: It does not work. Now my website .fr is no https. Please see my complementary comment in my question (add)

Comment: Nobody can help me?